# How to throw exception in Stored procedure Oracle for lock in table

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures

I have a Stored procedure in Oracle for getting and displaying data. But I want to implement one more functionality in it.

*What I want, I want to throw an exception and that exception I want to log into an Oracle table*

**Sample Stored procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_FCA_GISDATA(
                                            P_GRPNAME    IN NVARCHAR2, 
                                            TBLDATA_APP OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
                                           ) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN TBLDATA_APP FOR

      SELECT IP.ID,
             IP.SAP_ID,
             IP.ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
             IP.ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,
             IP.RRH_COUNTCHANGE,
             IP.RRH_CHANGEDDATE,
             IP.TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE,
             IP.TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE,
             ST.STATUS,
             IP.RFE1_DATE_BAND,
             IP.RFS_DATE_BAND,
             IP.CREATED_BY
        FROM TBL_IPCOLO_MAST_INFO IP
        LEFT JOIN TBL_IPCOLO_STATUS ST
          ON IP.FCA_STATUS = ST.ID
       WHERE UMS_GRP_TO_NAME = P_GRPNAME
         AND ST.ISACTIVE = 1
       ORDER BY 12 DESC;

    COMMIT;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;  
END GET_FCA_GISDATA;
```

Please suggest how to throw the exception.

Comment: That procedure will never throw an error on locked rows; it's the program that takes that ref cursor and processes it that needs to handle the error.

Comment: @Boneist: ohh, i see.. can u suggest some sample to throw a custom error ?? any idea

Comment: What's the reason behind this request? How is your procedure being referenced? There's not enough information here to tell you what you need to do. You can't force an error to occur when you open the cursor because all that does is set up a piece of code ("the execution plan") that tells Oracle how to fetch the next row(s). It doesn't actually fetch the rows. And, as a select statement, it doesn't actually care about if rows are locked or not.

Comment: @Boneist if inside the loop he was doing dml ( updating insertng or deleting data ) then might got an error exception right ?

Comment: @Moudiz if the sample procedure had showed how the ref cursor was to be used, then yes, an error could be handled. However, the sample procedure as written could never return an error about locked rows.

Answer (score 1):

How to raise your own exception? Like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2    my_ex exception;
  3  begin
  4    raise my_ex;
  5  exception
  6    when my_ex then
  7      dbms_output.put_line('My exception');
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test
My exception

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Instead of *displaying it* on the screen, you'd store it into some table.

Answer (score 0):

*a SQL Select statement like the below one might be added, provided the related synonyms of dynamic performance views' select privileges are granted to your current user :*

```
Select count(1)
  Into v_locked
  From all_objects o
  Join v$locked_object l on o.object_id = l.object_id
  Join v$session s on l.session_id = s.sid
  Join v$session_wait w on s.sid = w.sid
 Where o.object_name = 'TBL_IPCOLO_MAST_INFO'
   and s.status = 'ACTIVE'
   and lower(w.event) like '%enq%contention%' --> "enq: TX - row lock contention"
```

*before invoking the cursor.*

*If `v_locked` variable's value is greater than `zero` then the related table has a `row lock contention`. That would be alerted and logged in a simple table if `v_locked > 0`.*